# Right usage of "is due to get"

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

Could anybody tell me is this sentence OK to use in a scientific paper? Do you have any other recommendation?

...and we came to the conclusion that trying to keep a balance between method-1 and method-2 is due to get an appropriate result.

Comment: It's just a misuse of the word *due* - which in some other contexts is interchangeable with alternatives like *necessary, required*, but not here. Use one of those alternatives (or *essential*, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t understand what the sentence is meant to mean.  So, you should find an alternative.  Do you mean:

> We came to the conclusion that trying to keep a balance between method-1 and method-2 *would* get an appropriate result.

If so, you might also consider the following changes:

- *trying to balance method-1 and method-2* (more concise), or maybe just *balancing*
- *would produce/yield an appropriate result* (more stylistically appropriate than *get*)

Also, *method 1* (or *Method 1*) looks better to me that *method-1*.  This would add up to:

> We came to the conclusion that balancing methods 1 and 2 would yield an appropriate result.

Or even:

> We concluded that balancing methods 1 and 2 would yield an appropriate result.

Comment: Glad to help.  You can click the tick to show that you accept an answer.  Leave it open if you want to accumulate some other answers.